# Solving a boolean equation with a recursive function

Tags: c++, recursion, boolean-expression, boolean-operations, boolean-algebra

I'm trying to code a function that takes a boolean equation as its input, and gives the answer of the equation as its output. For example:

> Input: T & F | F

> Output: F

However when I code it, there's this error that appears: "Non-void function does not return a value in all control paths" in my boolFunc function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

bool boolFunc(char* input, long len){
    if(len == 1){
        if(*input == 'T')
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
    
    else{
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            if(*(input + i) == '&'){
                return boolFunc(input, i) && boolFunc(input+i+1, len-i);
            }
            if(*(input + i) == '|'){
                return boolFunc(input, i) || boolFunc(input+i+1, len-i);
            }
        }
    }
}


int main(){
    char input[500] = {'\0'};
    cin.getline(input, 500);
    
    if(boolFunc(input,strlen(input)))
        cout << "T";
    else
        cout << "F";
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The error message tells exactly what the problem is. To fix it, make sure `boolFunc` returns a value in all possible cases. Consider for example what happens if you call `boolFunc("", 0)` or `boolFunc("1 2", 3)`.

Comment: The compiler can't tell what will happen in your `else` branch if `*(input)` is neither `&` or `|`. What happens if `A` is input? Your code should handle that case, or at least add a default return value before the closing bracket of the function.

Comment: thank you for your quick replies! I edited my code and now I think there is a return in all control paths, but the error is still there, what am I not seeing?

Comment: Pop quiz: if the following statement `if(flag == false)` evaluates to "false", that is, if `flag` is true, what does your function return in that case?

Comment: i@SamVarshavchik if flag is true, then it means there is already a return (return boolFunc(input, i) || boolFunc(input+i+1, len-i) or return boolFunc(input, i) && boolFunc(input+i+1, len-i)) ?

Comment: @HengWei All changes you made in the last edit are equivalent to adding a `return false;` at the very bottom of the original `boolFunc`. But you complicated the code to the point where the compiler doesn't recognize that.

Comment: yeah you're right, just corrected it!

Answer (score 2):

I fixed the error, although there might be another logic error, in the case T|F&F, the order of operations must follow the right order (left to right)

```
bool boolFunc(char* input, long len){
    if(len == 1){
        if(*input == 'T')
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
    
    else{
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            if(*(input + i) == '&'){
                return boolFunc(input, i) && boolFunc(input+i+1, len-i);
            }
            if(*(input + i) == '|'){
                return boolFunc(input, i) || boolFunc(input+i+1, len-i);
            }
        }
    }
    //CORRECTION 
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain the changes you made to the original code a little bit (such as what the issue is, and how you specifically fixed it)? They will be helpful to the author of the question and other readers.

Comment: ok! I decided to answer my own question, because someone gave me a hint in the comments

Comment: Much appreciated, thank you for taking the time to add it.